# Mac OS X - Validation message reporting

Tags: cocoa, macos, validation, message

What is the usual way to display validation messages (e.g. 'Name cannot be blank', 'Email address invalid' etc.) on a Mac? I've been messing around with itunes and Finder and the best I could get were pop up messages:

[image: Itunes error]
[image: Finder error]

Comment: The screenshot from the Finder you've shown is actually a poor message box. You should design your dialogs so that, just looking at the buttons, you can tell the question. For instance, in this case, the buttons should rather read 'Cancel' and 'Use "." as the first character'.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS, there are two easy ways to show warning messages and confirmation dialogs.

The first way, if you want to display a warning because of an `NSError`, is to use `[NSApp presentError:(NSError*)]`.

The second way is to use the [`NSAlert`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Once your alert is configured, you can either present it modal to your application (through `-runModal`) or to a window (through `– beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`). If you're using the `NSDocument` architecture, you'll rather want errors from documents to display alerts modal to a window, since otherwise you'll freeze up everything in your app until the user responds.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a standard way of reporting the errors. For the web, this has become red text above the form, with the error location highlighted somehow. Is there a common practise like this for macs? Opening a new window, or displaying an alert seems a bit tedious from a user point of view